# unable to decode json with text in get request

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I need to create GET request like this:

[https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=Чер](https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80)

[https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=Володимирович](https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Last characters after = are Cyrillic symbols

I make get request something like this:

```
 var hostURL = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q="
hostURL = hostURL + searchConditions

let escapedSearchConditions = hostURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

let url = URL(string: escapedSearchConditions!)!
```

Request is:
https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE

that return necessary data from server but returned data can't be decoded.
it works fine with integers in search condition but not with Cyrillic text(

```
import Foundation

struct Declarant: Codable {
var id: String
var firstname: String
var lastname: String
var placeOfWork: String
var position: String
var linkPDF: String

}

struct DeclarationInfo: Codable {
let items: [Declarant]

}
```

import Foundation

```
struct DeclarationInfoController {

func fetchDeclarationInfo (with searchConditions: String, completion: @escaping(DeclarationInfo?) -> Void) {
    var hostURL = "https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/?q="
    hostURL = hostURL + searchConditions

    let escapedSearchConditions = hostURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

    let url = URL(string: escapedSearchConditions!)!

    print(url)

    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        print("Trying to decode data...")

        if let data = data,
            let declarationInfo = try? jsonDecoder.decode(DeclarationInfo.self, from: data) {
            completion(declarationInfo)
            print(declarationInfo)
        } else {
            print("Either no data was returned, or data was not properly decoded.")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }

    dataTask.resume()
}


}


import UIKit

class DeclarationViewController: UIViewController {

let declarationInfoController = DeclarationInfoController()

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func beginSearchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    declarationInfoController.fetchDeclarationInfo(with: searchBar.text!) { (declarationInfo) in
        if let declarationInfo = declarationInfo {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.resultLabel.text = declarationInfo.items[0].lastname
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the definition of `DeclarationInfo`. I get `ЧЕРАХ` with exactly the same code as you have shown, just that I used my own version of `DeclarationInfo`.

Comment: OOPer, updated with DeclarationInfo. Please look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

```
if let data = data,
            let declarationInfo = try? jsonDecoder.decode(DeclarationInfo.self, from: data) {
            completion(declarationInfo)
            print(declarationInfo)
        } else {
            print("Either no data was returned, or data was not properly decoded.")
            completion(nil)
        }
```

by

```
 do {
       if let data = data {
        let declarationInfo = try jsonDecoder.decode(DeclarationInfo.self, from: data) 
        completion(declarationInfo)
        print(declarationInfo)
        return
    } catch {
        print(error) 
    }
    completion(nil)
```

You will have the error printed, ans do you will know why decoding fails

Answer (score 1):

**Never ever** use `try?` ignoring the error while decoding JSON. `Codable` errors are incredibly descriptive and tell you exactly what's wrong.

Use **always** a `do catch` block like

```
do {
    let declarationInfo = try jsonDecoder.decode(DeclarationInfo.self, from: data)
} catch { print error }
```

and print the `error` rather than useless literal strings.

---

The error has nothing to do with Cyrillic text.

The suggested JSON struct in the comments of [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446429/decoding-complicated-json-objects-in-swift)

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id, firstname, lastname, placeOfWork: String
    let position, linkPDF: String
}
```

reveals the error (the most significant parts are emphasized)

> **keyNotFound**(CodingKeys(stringValue: **"position"**, intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: **"items"**, intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: **"Index 11"**, intValue: 11)], debugDescription: "**No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"position\"**, intValue: nil) (\"position\").", underlyingError: nil))

It clearly describes that in the struct `Item` there is no value for key `position` in the item at index 11 of the array.

The solution is to declare this particular struct member as optional

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id, firstname, lastname, placeOfWork: String
    let position : String?
    let linkPDF: String
}
```

Once again: **Don't ignore errors, they help you to fix the issues instantly.**

Comment: Completely agree. *Especially* with `Codable` errors. It's almost impossible to figure out where a `Codable` went wrong without looking at the error, since there aren't any functions in which you can set breakpoints.